# How to move an IP address in Azure from one VM to another?

Tags: azure, azure-networking, azure-vm

I have an old VM with a static IP address - let's say IP address A.  I want to dissociate this IP address from the old VM, make a new VM, and then associate IP address A with the new VM.  They would be in the same region and same zone.

Have not been able to find any useful documentation on this.  If I try to Dissociate the IP, then make a new VM, then stop that VM and Dissociate that VM's IP, I am not able to Associate IP address A with the new VM (it doesn't show up on the list of network interfaces that it can be associated to).

How do I actually do this?

Comment: when you say old, how old? Is there a chance it is a cloud service VM and not ARM?

Comment: @SamCogan No it is ARM - just a year or so old

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to assign an IP address to a VM assuming the following are true:

- The IP you want to assign is not currently assigned
- The VM you are assigning to does not have an IP already assigned to the NIC
- The IP and NIC are in the same region

Given that the IP is not showing up in your list, my guess would be that it is not in the same region as your VM/NIC. If all of the above are true then you may need to raise a support request.